# How to replace a specific package to be installed with apt

Tags: apt, updates, ssh, ppa

I am trying to replace the standard SSH client with this one:

https://launchpad.net/~yoda-jazz-kc/+archive/ubuntu/hpn-ssh

How can I get Ubuntu 16.04 to replace the standard openssh-client with this one and ALWAYS update from this repository?

I have added the PPA and have been able to install it by specifying the exact version with `apt-get install openssh-client=vvvvvv`. However, it is replaced with the standard version when the system is updated.

I have tried configuring `/etc/apt/preferences` and also putting the PPA at the top of list in sources.list, but it makes no difference.

I've read dozens of articles about how to configure apt to supposedly do this, but they are mostly confusing or flat-out wrong.

I need specific advice on how to do this, not generic instructions that assume a detailed understanding about the vagaries of apt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First create a pin file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` naming it `pin-openssh-client` or whatever you want.
2. Put these lines in the file

   ```
   Package: openssh-client
   Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ```
3. Save the file and check the priority of the package by `apt-cache policy openssh-client`.

I added the PPA. The output of the command after adding the pin is

```
openssh-client:
  Installed: 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:7.1p2-hpn14v9-2~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
     1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu1 500
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:7.2p2-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1:7.1p2-hpn14v9-2~ubuntu16.04.1 1001
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yoda-jazz-kc/hpn-ssh/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

From the output, It's seen that the package from the PPA is taking preference over the package provided by the repository (Check the `Candidate` line).

If you already installed the package, remove it. Then reinstall to get the one from PPA.

Hope that works!

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly and it no longer tries to replace the package with the standard version when I run `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: In case anyone wants to replace the SSH server too, you need to add files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` for `openssh-server` and `openssh-sftp-server`